# 1 Character in path changing... How to Handle?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have a path:
    \%VARIABLE%svr0001\e$\Users\%VARIABLE%POS00??\E2ELOGS*.dbg

The ONLY characters that changes is the '??' (%VARIABLE%POS00??).

- Values could be from 01 through 15 (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15)

How would I make the following script work without creating if path exist statements for every potential changing value:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\%VARIABLE%svr0001\e$\Users\%VARIABLE%POS00??\E2ELOGS\*.dbg"') do (
  set "$line=%%a"
  set "$lastchar=!$line:~-1!"
  if !$lastchar! gtr 0 echo %%a >>NO_ACK_ERROR-2.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%x in (1,1,15) do (
  set "$number=0%%x"
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\%VARIABLE%svr0001\e$\Users\%VARIABLE%POS00!$number:~-2!\E2ELOGS\*.dbg"') do (
     set "$line=%%a"
     set "$lastchar=!$line:~-1!"
     if !$lastchar! gtr 0 echo %%a >>NO_ACK_ERROR-2.txt
))
```

Comment: This script very much works, however, the cmd screen does not close when the script completes and stays open until I close it manually.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correct, you want to check the log files with the name POS001-POS0015, below may be the answer for you.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%i in (1,1,15) do (
set "num=%%i"
if "!num:~0,1!" neq "0" set "num=0!num!"
set "filepath=\\%VARIABLE%svr0001\e$\Users\%VARIABLE%POS00!num!\E2ELOGS\*.dbg"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('find /c /i "Error   : -2" "!filepath!"') do (
  set "$line=%%a"
  set "$lastchar=!$line:~-1!"
  if !$lastchar! gtr 0 echo %%a >>NO_ACK_ERROR-2.txt
)
```

Cheers, G

Comment: This script does not complete, trying to throw a pause in it to see where it's going wrong, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: I edited Values could be from 01 through 15 (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15) MAYBE that helps...?

Comment: Still not completing the script, something its not liking in there.

Comment: @gbabu you are setting the `num` variable but used `%%i` where `!num!` should be.  It is also missing a closing parenthesis, and the counter should start at 1.

Comment: @foxidrive thanks for pointing that out. Corrected the errors now.

Comment: The test for 15 will fail too.

Comment: Why would it fail for 15. Should i change the for loop to 1,1,16. Not with the computer now so unable to test it.